# Using jquery, how do I obtain the value of a @Html.Hidden field in a selected row of a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

Given the following table, I know how to get the value of the first , but how can I use jquery to obtain the value of @Html.Hidden("AccountId")? Assume that a certain row is already selected, ala:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
        $("#tblTaskList").delegate("tr", "click", function () {
            $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");            
            var tids = $(this).find('td').first();
        });
</script>
```

and here is the table:

```
<table id="tblTaskList"> 
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Ticket ID</th>                
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tblBody" class="tblBody">        
        @{for (var ix = 0; ix < Model.Value.Count - 1; ix++)
          { 
            <tr id="@(Model.Value[ix].TicketId)">
                <td style="width: 5%">@Model.Value[ix].TicketId</td>
                @Html.Hidden("AccountId");
            </tr>        
          }}
    </tbody>  
<table>
```

Thanks so much for the help

Comment: Why not use the HTML5 data attributes? http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/ and with jQuery http://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously you don't want the hidden value to be alert()'d, but didn't know what you wanted to do with it at that point. This will give you the val() of the hidden field within that . Hope this helps!

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    $("#tblTaskList").on("click", "tr", function () {
        $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");            
        var tids = $(this).find('td').first();
        alert($(this).find('input:hidden').val());
    });
</script>
```

Comment: awesome!  pointage to you.   but what if i have two hidden fields?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with both fields, basically you'd just do a $(this).find('input:hidden').each(function () { console.log($(this).val()); });

Answer (score 0):

The `@Html.Hidden` method renders an `input` element of type `hidden` - You can use the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
var hidden = $(this).find('input[type=hidden]').first();
```

eg:

```
$("#tblTaskList").delegate("tr", "click", function () {
    var self = $(this);
    self.addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");            
    var tids = self.find('td').first();
    var hidden = self.find('input[type=hidden]').first();
    ...
});
```